# Why an asynchronous AJAX block the document ready event on firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
  function runFirst() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'src/bigRequest.php',
        data: {"name": "myName"},
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(detail) {
          console.log("Got data!");
        }
    });
  }

  runFirst();

  $(function(){
    console.log("Document ready.");
  });

  console.log("Page end.");
</script>
```

This is a simple code, notice the bigRequest.php will not quickly return a result as the network or computing reasons.  Why does "Document ready." come out at the end?  What's so special about this AJAX running in main thread?

Comment: When I run that code locally, even with quite a small response to the ajax, I get `Page end.` then `Document ready.` then `Got data!` -- e.g., the `ready` callback ran before the ajax success callback ran. What makes you think the ajax is holding up the `ready`? I suspect something *else* is responsible for that. There's no reason an asynchronous ajax call would prevent the things jQuery calls "ready." (That said: There's really no point to `ready`. Just use `defer` on your `script`, or put it at the end of `body`.)

Comment: I've managed to come up with a way to make it *seem* like the ajax holds up `ready`: If I start the ajax call and then use `document.write` to write out other scripts to load. If there are enough of them, I can make the ajax call complete before all the scripts are retrieved and run. But if the ajax response is large, I see the scripts load and the ready callback run before the ajax completes. Still, if the other scripts were big enough or slow enough to load... But it's not the ajax that's holding things up, unless you're saturating the max number on concurrent requests to the same site.

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder, thanks for your answer.  Actually when I testing this issue, I blocked the code on server side so that the URL could not quickly return a result, this is the key point.  I just tried to update the latest Chrome, this issue is missing.  But maybe you can find it on Firefox still.

Comment: Can't repro: https://torch-cubic-macaw.glitch.me/

Answer (score -1):

Javascript works in ticks cycles.
When you do not explicitly ask for timeout (with `setTimeout()` for example), the code inside your lambda function will be executed in the second tick, while the  log message "Page end" is executed in the first tick.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Page end.");
}, 1);
```

In order to understand it better, try this code:

```
$(function(){
  let now1 = new Date();
  let ticks1 = now1.getTime();
  console.log("Document ready: ", ticks1);
});

let now2 = new Date();
let ticks2 = now2.getTime();
console.log("Page end: ", ticks2);
```